# How do I stop my name from being invisible?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My name is invisible. I can't write my user name when I join an online server, it says invalid name! How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Make your name have no spaces in it that happens to me to but I fixed it. So NO SPACES